# how to getting datagridview datas for another windows form in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I have two windows from. Form-1 has  a data_grid_view and Add button. Form-2 has text boxes. I want that when I select a data from data_grid_view and click Add button then this data come to the text box in Form-2 form with the help of c#.

Answer (score 0):

one option is to pass the information into Form2 constructor from Form1

in Form 1 you will add the below code in the button click event. from the designer you you can double click the button to create the even for you automatically, usually named the name of you button with "_Click" appended to it:

```
protected void btnInFormOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    data1 = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    data2 = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

    Form2 frm2 = new Form2(data1,data2);
    frm2.show();
}
```

in Form 2:

```
public Form2(string data1, string data2) //this is your constructor
{
    txtBox.Text = data1;
    txtBoxName.Text = data2;
}
```

i am assuming that you have already parsed the data in your datagridview into variables.
you need to tell exactly where is not working and post what you have done so far. if this helps, mark as answer.

Comment: This is not work. I'm a new coder. Can you give example for this code?

Answer (score 0):

You could fill the textboxes directly before you show the form:

```
Form2 NewForm2 =  new Form2();
NewForm2.TextBox0.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
NewForm2.TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
NewForm2.Show();
```